# Ansible filter to know if an item exist base on child list values

Tags: ansible

This seems a pretty simple task, but I cannot find a systematic documentation or tutorials on things like json_query, map, etc. Only examples that I cannot fit them in. Recommend one please if you know.

Have a list structured as below. The number of stores, items and item names may vary.

```
stores:
  - name: store1
    state: closed
    items:
      - apple
      - banana
  - name: store2
    state: open
    items:
      - apple
      - banana
  - name: store3
    state: closeout
    items:
      - apple
      - orange
```

Here is my task:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Apple is on the market"
  when: ***< need help to get a condition here >***
```

The *when* condition above needs
**the *stores* contains store with state not 'closed' and items contains 'apple'**

Want to use *when* instead of any loop to avoid the msg posted more than once.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the list (with Jinja2 filters), then apply `| list | length > 0` at the end.

```
when: >-
  stores
  | selectattr('items', 'contains', 'apple')
  | rejectattr('state', 'eq', 'closed')
  | list | length > 0
```

Note: the `>-` allows you to lay out the `when` condition over several lines, for clarity; if you prefer, you can instead write it as a `"`-quoted string, but it gets more confusing after the first one or two filters:

```
when: "stores | selectattr('items', 'contains', 'apple') | rejectattr('state', 'eq', 'closed') | list | length > 0"
```

Comment: I tested this and ended up using this in my code. It's true with >- there, it looks much nicer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Q: *"**Condition: stores with state not 'closed' contain item 'apple'**"*

A: Use the test [*in*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#in) and reject blacklisted states. Create a list of states you want to reject, e.g.

```yaml
    black_list:
      - closed
      - closeout
```

Then the task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Apple is on the market"
      vars:
        _not_closed: "{{ stores|rejectattr('state', 'in', black_list)|list }}"
      when: "'apple' in _not_closed|map(attribute='items')|flatten"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Apple is on the market
```

---

Explanation

1. Reject blacklisted states

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _not_closed }}"
      vars:
        _not_closed: "{{ stores|rejectattr('state', 'in', black_list)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - items:
    - apple
    - banana
    name: store2
    state: open
```

2. Map and flatten items

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _not_closed|map(attribute='items')|flatten }}"
      vars:
        _not_closed: "{{ stores|rejectattr('state', 'in', black_list)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - apple
  - banana
```

3. Test whether an apple is among the items or not

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ 'apple' in _not_closed|map(attribute='items')|flatten }}"
      vars:
        _not_closed: "{{ stores|rejectattr('state', 'in', black_list)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: true
```

Comment: This also worked and clean. It didn't work on my first try, so I ended up using the other answer. It's good to know a variable can be defined like this.

Comment: Rejecting a scalar in the first step and selecting from the shorter list in the second step is more efficient.